# Comments array / loop not looping

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to loop all the comments from the `$feed` while loop, however, its only displaying one comment, what am I doing wrong? If I remove the name, they loop.
How can I name the comment while loop? I think that may solve my problem. Below is my current code

```
$rows = array();
while($feed = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $query_ppimage = "SELECT id, post_id, relation, userID, file_format FROM media WHERE userID = '".$feed['userID']."' AND relation = 'profile_picture' UNION ALL SELECT -1 id, '55529055162cf' post_id, 'profile_picture' relation, '0' userID, 'jpg' file_format ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $qppimg = $conn->query($query_ppimage);
        while($ppimg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qppimg)) {
        $newrow = $feed;
        if($feed['relation'] == 'page'){
            $query_type = "SELECT name as 'page_name' FROM pages WHERE id = '".$feed['relation_id']."'";
            $typeload = $conn->query($query_type);
            while($type = mysqli_fetch_assoc($typeload)) {
            $newrow['postto'] = $type;
            }
        }
            $newrow['ppimage'] = $ppimg;
        }
        $comment_load = "SELECT * FROM media_comments WHERE post_id = '".$feed['post_id']."'";
        $comments = $conn->query($comment_load);
        while($com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments)) {   
            $newrow['comments'] = $com; 
        }       
$rows[] = $newrow;      
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: This looks like PHP-- are you sure your tags are right?

Comment: Aah sorry about that, I thought I added a PHP tag, my mistake

Comment: You keep overwriting `$newrow['comments']` in the while loop toward the bottom of the code.  You could make $newrow['comments'] an array and add new elements to it, or you could concatenate its current value with the value from the database, depending on how you are prepared to deal with it in the front end.

Comment: @James How would I name the comment while loop?

Comment: Append to `$newrow['comments']` instead of overwriting it: `$newrow['comments'][] = $com;`

Comment: @Terry Could you add this as the answer so I can mark it as the answer. Worked perfectly thank you :)

Comment: @CassieJRound Will do :) glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, the issue you are facing is that in each iteration in the `while` loop, you are **overwriting `$newrow['comments']`**. Therefore, you will only get a single value at the end of the loop, and it will be the final value it encounters in the while loop.

What you want is actually to append your comment to it, using the [square bracket syntax of PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (i.e. by appending `[]`).

> This is done by assigning values to the array, specifying the key in brackets. The key can also be omitted, resulting in an empty pair of brackets (`[]`).
>
> ```
> $arr[key] = value;
> $arr[] = value;
> // key may be an integer or string
> // value may be any value of any type
> ```
>
> If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created,

That means doing this:

```
while($com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments)) {
    $newrow['comments'][] = $com;
}
```